# How to make ProgressBar undragable back?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I Have a ProgressBar which is being used to select a value from 0 to max, Now everything is working good, However sometimes i would like to limit the ProgressBar to not be able to scroll back.
The Bar is being used to select max players, later on the players are being chosen, and i want to block the abillity to set max players to lower then chosen players.

Meaning that if the bar is set to 6, at some condition i want to make it unscrollable back, but only forward.

**I Don't want to change the minimum**, cause that will change the bar.

How can i achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may inherit `MyProgressBar` from `ProgressBar` and override `setProgress()` with your own version, which will check if the new value is bigger than current or not.

Comment: Yes but it won't block it. i'm not sure about they way the ProgressBar class is built.

Comment: please, copy/paste the code and explain, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well i was mistaken i am using SeekBar and not progress bar, and i solved the issue but his answer is most likley correct. Thank you though lenik :)